# Perform event after winform is shown C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform application with 2 forms, I am calling one form `MainForm` from `PasswordForm`.

First I set the constructor

```
private MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
```

Then I show the form

```
mainForm.Show();
```

However, there is about a 2 second delay in loading the form, because of a number of SQL queries that run on the form load event.

Is there any way I can call an event after the mainForm is shown? (specifically I want to fade out the PasswordForm, which I currently use this

```
FadeOut(this, 100);
```

I've tried calling from the `MainForm_Shown` event but haven't found a way of referring to the `PasswordForm` form?

```
    private void MainForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // THIS WILL FADE OUT THE 'MAINFORM' BUT I WANT TO FADE OUT THE 'PASSWORDFORM'
        FadeOut(this, 100);
    }
```

**EDIT** Both forms are using the same namespace.

Comment: Follow the steps here to pass a reference of 1 form to another : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38460510/3185569 then call any public method of that form.

Answer (score -1):

Use open forms:

```
private void MainForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dynamic frm = Application.OpenForms["mainForm"];
    frm.FadeOut(this, 100);
}
```